# ERROR Database:40 - java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I use database.properties to save my database information. However, it pop up this error, every time I run the code. I don't know which part of the database is wrong. Please help!

```
host: 127.0.0.1
port: 3306
database: spider
username: root
password: !QAZxsw2
driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
drivertype: MYSQL
```

> ERROR Database:40 - java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed to parse the
>   host:port pair
>   '127.0.0.1:3306;databaseName=spider;user=root;password=!QAZxsw2;serverTimezone=UTC&amp'.

Comment: I use this string ```String connString = String.format("jdbc:%s://%s:%s;databaseName=%s;user=%s;password=%s;serverTimezone=UTC&amp", drivertype, host, port, database, username,  password);``` as my connection string.

Comment: @user7294900 I googled it and the meaning of adding ```&amp``` is that "There are multiple params that need to be separated by &, but & is changed to &amp;"

Comment: `&amp` isn't `&amp;` and is irrelevant if no other parameter after. You should add more info to question

Comment: @user7294900 So, there's nothing wrong in my database.properties file? I thought the error is because of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using SQL Server JDBC driver syntax for the URL, while you are using the MySQL JDBC driver.

See [MySQL Connector/J 8, Connection URL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html), the URL to connect to MySQL would be:

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spider?user=root&password=!QAZxsw2&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Note that I also removed the `&amp;` you had, which has no place in a URL, unless you are putting it in XML and want to escape the `&` between key-value pairs.

Given the syntax of JDBC URLs is undefined, except for the `jdbc:<sub-protocol>:` prefix, you cannot try to dynamically construct it like you are doing and expect it to work on different drivers. Each driver has their own syntax, and although there is considerable overlap in syntax, each has their own idiosyncrasies (if not outright outlandish syntax). Instead, use a single property for the entire URL, or use a driver-specific strategy.

Answer (score 0):

After I post this question, I found out that my connection string was wrong. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:%s/%s?serverTimezone=UTC&"+"user=%s&password=%s` It should be like that url pattern of mysql.